# Rotate by point (left down corner)

Tags: easeljs, tweenjs

How do rotate by point in Bitmap? I need rotate hande by left down corner.

tweenjs, easeljs

[image]

THX.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation uses the registration point (top-left for Bitmaps by default), but you can also set `regX` and `regY` to change where the origin of the element is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regX` and `regY` properties of the Bitmap object to change the offset of the registration point of it.

For purposes of your question: If you want to use the left down corner, the coordinates you need to specify are **(0, imgHeight)**, where **imgHeight** is the height of your image used to create your Bitmap.

```
hand.regX = 0;
hand.regY = imgHeight;
```

In the case of the value for the `regY` property, you can assign it manually, or you can also use the `getTransformedBounds()` method to get the height.

```
var handRect = hand.getTransformedBounds();
hand.regY = handRect.height;
```